# CakePHP use user_id in model on registration

Tags: registration, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to add an Adress and at the same time add/register the user. So the saved adress has the user_id of the user. **Saving adress and user always leaves the user_id field in adresses empty.**

Maybe I should do it the other way arround? So add all that to the users controller?

The user is not registered at this point by the way.

USERS Table

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('users');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasOne('Adresses');        
    }
```

Adresses Table

```
public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('adresses');
        $this->displayField('name');
        $this->primaryKey('id');
        $this->hasOne('Users', [
            'foreignKey'  => 'user_id'
        ]);      

    }
```

Add Function in Adresses Controller

public function add()    {

```
$move = $this->Adresses->newEntity();
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $adress= $this->Adresses->patchEntity($adress, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => [
            'Users'
        ]
    ]);

    if ($this->Adresses->save($adress, ['associated' => ['Users']])) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('bla'));

        //return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'pages','action' => 'display','success']);
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('Bla'));
        //return $this->redirect( ['controller' =>'adresses', 'action' => 'display', 'add-fail']);
    }
}
$this->set(compact('adress'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['adress']);
```

}

Comment: Why don't you use [**associations**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html) and [**save both**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-associations) at once?

Comment: I am using 'associated' => ['Users'] already.

Comment: I am using $this->hasOne('Users'); in my Adresses Table and $this->Adresses->save($adress, ['associated' => ['Users']]) in my Adress Controller

Comment: Then maybe update your question with the code that you are using, and explain the actual problem with it - at least to me it's now even more unclear what you are actually asking for.

Comment: @ndm, thanks. I updated the question with the code

Comment: Your question is still lacking an explanation of the actual technical problem that you are facing with that code. While I can see a problem, shooting in the dark is not overly constructive, and questions without a clear problem statement are not too helpful for future readers.

Comment: Saving adress and user always leaves the user_id field in adresses empty. That is the problem. So it is not connected with my user

Comment: I see. you've setup the wrong type of association on your `AdressesTable` class, since it holds the foreign key, it should be associated to `Users` via a `belongsTo` association. If that's all there is, then I'd probably tend towards closing the question, as the problem is merely more than a typo.

Comment: @ndm damn! Thanks a lot, I am such a .... Good thing about situations like that, I will never forget :)